# Mudar a posição da legenda no gráfico ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou tentando colocar a legenda embaixo de um conjunto de gráficos, mas o código não funciona. Mas costumava funcionar.

O meu DF é mais ou menos assim:

| UTI | Faixa etária | Trimestre | Letalidade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sim | 60 a 69 | Mar-Abr-Mai, 20 | 52,4 |
| Sim | 70 a 79 | Jun-Jul-Ago, 21 | 48,5 |
| Não | 90 ou + | Dez-Jan-Fev | 61,6 |
| Não | 80 a 89 | Set-Out-Nov, 20 | 42,3 |
| Sim | 60 a 69 | Mar-Abr-Mai, 21 | 45,0 |
| Não | 70 a 79 | Jun-Jul-Ago, 20 | 57,1 |
| NA | 90 ou + | Mar-Abr-Mai, 20 | 79,8 |

O código dos gráficos são assim:

```
fig.letal.uti.trim6 <- letal.uti %>%
  filter(Trimestre ==  "Jun-Jul-Ago, 21", UTI != "NA") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = UTI, y = letalidade,  fill = `Faixa etária`) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label=letalidade),position=position_stack(0.5),
            hjust=0.5, family = "serif", size = 4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = met.brewer("NewKingdom", 4)) +
  labs(y = "", subtitle = "Jun-Jul-Ago, 21",
       fill = "Faixa etária"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

Uso o seguinte comando pra juntar:

```
combined.letal.uti <- fig.letal.uti.trim1 + fig.letal.uti.trim2 + 
fig.letal.uti.trim3 + fig.letal.uti.trim4 + fig.letal.uti.trim5 + 
fig.letal.uti.trim6 + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que a legenda ficasse embaixo. Como faço?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: vc pode adicionar ao seu código esse comando `theme(legend.spacing.x = unit(0.1, 'cm'), legend.position = c(0.1, 0.1))`. `c(0.1,0.1)` é as coordenadas, se nao der certo vc ajustando as coordenadas

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para incluir um exemplo reproduzível dos seus dados. Também indique os pacotes que está utilizando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer o gráfico que deseja de maneira bem mais simples com `facet_wrap`. Como não forneceu um exemplo reproduzível dos seus dados, estou simulando um conjunto:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(9826)
dados <- data.frame(
  UTI = rep(c('Sim', 'Não'), each = 12),
  Faixa = rep(rep(letters[1:3], each = 4), 2),
  Trimestre = rep(paste("Trimestre", 1:4), 6),
  Letalidade = sample(20:80, 24))

ggplot(dados, aes(UTI, Letalidade, fill = Faixa)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Letalidade), position = position_stack(0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Trimestre) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigada. Ajudou muito. Eu não tinha pensando em utilizar o facet wrap, bem mais prático.